# Access class methods

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm having a problem. I have a unit test that is trying to access methods from a class. My unit test is as follows

```
public function testReverseArraySuccess()
    {
        $data = "This is a test.";

        $output = (new Reverse)
            ->setInput($data)
            ->get();

        $this->assertEquals(['test', 'a', 'is', 'This'], $output);
    }
```

My class is a follows

```
class Reverse
{
    public $input;

    /**
     *
     * @param $data
     */
    public function setInput($data) {
        $this->input = $data;
    }

    /**
     *
     *@return void
     */
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->input;
    }
}
```

How can I setup my class so that my Test will pass?
The error I get when I run the test is.

Error : Call to a member function get() on null

Comment: I just want to know how to set my class so that I can access the class and methods of the class like it does in the test. @hakre

Comment: Yes it gives my the error that's in my question.

Comment: When I run the test it gives me this error. "Call to a member function get() on null"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234732/discussion-between-eric-evans-and-hakre).

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php - OPs problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInput` isn't chainable since it's not returning an instance of itself. It's a `void` function that returns null by default that's why you're getting that error message. Update `setInput` to return an instance of the class to make it chainable.

```php
public function setInput($data) {
    $this->input = $data;
    
    return $this;
}
```

Now `get` will return whatever value is passed to the `input` property, here's a working [demo](https://3v4l.org/NZs4r).

Then it's a matter of reversing the input, but I'll leave that up OP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call get data directly after set data by instance of Reverse class.

```
public function testReverseArraySuccess() {

   $data = "This is a test."; 

   $output = new Reverse;
   $output->setInput($data);

   $this->assertEquals(['test', 'a', 'is', 'This'], $output->get());
}
```